# low pass filter android accelerometer measurements for given cut off frequency

Tags: android, accelerometer, lowpass-filter

I was reading a research paper which deals with gait monitoring using android accelerometer sensor data values at 50 Hz. It uses a low pass filter to filter the noise with a cut-off frequency of 8 Hz.

 This is the pseudo code for Low Pass Filter i got from wikipedia:

```
for i from 1 to n
   y[i] := y[i-1] + α * (x[i] - y[i-1])
```

how should i set the value of α so that this works at 8 Hz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula to calculate alpha.

> α := dt / (T + dt)
> T = 1/fc, dt = sampling interval

In your case

> dt = 1/50Hz = 0.02 **sec** <strike>ms</strike>
>
> T = 1/fc = 1/8 = 0.125 **sec** <strike>ms</strike>
>
> α = 0.02/(0.02 + 0.125) = 0.137931034

Take a look at [this link](http://www.kircherelectronics.com/blog/index.php/11-android/sensors/8-low-pass-filter-the-basics) for further explanation

EDIT:

Units are updated from msec to sec. Thanks to @IR_IR for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: The formula is correct but units is not.
dt = 1/50Hz = 0.02 ms -> it is not miliseconds it is seconds.
dt = 1/50Hz = 0.02 sec or dt = 1/50Hz = 20 ms.
Greeting.